# Magic Mouse / Wireless keyboard not fully functional after Archive & Install

Tags: settings, wifi, mouse

I'm having multiple issues with my 2008-model MacBook Pro.  I took it to the Genius Bar and they suggested an Archive & Install, which I did.  But now I have a new issue.

I have the wireless/bluetooth Apple Magic Mouse and Wireless Keyboard.  Since the Archive & Install, neither is working properly.  The mouse tracks and clicks, but the "touchpad" features like scrolling and swiping don't register at all.  Also, the function key on the wireless keyboard doesn't seem to do anything.

If I go to the System Preferences and select Mouse, then "setup Bluetooth Mouse" I get a "Searching..." and a spinning wheel forever.  The mouse is paired but I can't configure the Magic features.

Similarly for Keyboard.  It's paired, and I've clicked "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" so that if I want to use the keyboard to change the volume or something I should be able to use the combination Fn-F11.  But both F11 and Fn-F11 do an Exposé thing.  If I click "Set up Bluetooth Keyboard..." I also get "Searching..." and the eternally spinning wheel.

If I go to the Keyboard Viewer I see a keyboard layout that looks like the wireless one, but as soon as I press a key the Keyboard Viewer changes to a layout that looks more like the extended keyboard.  Pressing Fn changes the keycaps on the ⌫ key to ⌦ , and the arrow keys change, too, but actually pressing these key combinations doesn't do what it says it will do: Fn-⌫ and ⌫ are doing the same thing.

Casting the "put to sleep/wake up" and "restart" spells don't seem to have any effect.  Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new blank user to see if the user exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the suggestion.  A blank user has the same problem.

Comment: ....."Spell".... *Really*?

Comment: @Fake It took me a while to realize what you were talking about… then I realized that he… “casted a spell”. Oh my… ;)

Comment: @Martín Marconcini - I figured out what he meant immediately. That does not mean it isn't a terminally stupid way to think of how computers operate, though.

Comment: @FakeName: All I meant was there are some things we try just in case they might work.  Sorry if I came off sounding stupid.

Comment: Thinking of computers as being magical devices is **absolutely the worst thing** if you want to really learn how to use them. Magic is the **antitheses** of modern electronics. Magic is fundamentally a failure of cause and effect. With magic, you do X, and Y happens, with no connection between the two. With computers, You do X, and that *causes* Y to happen through a direct linkage. You may not *understand* how the two things are connected, but there *is a connection*. That is the root of modern science. Magical thinking prevents any deeper understanding of *why* things happen.

Comment: So yeah, there is no way to refer to computer operation as "Spells" without sounding *uneducated* (not necessarily *stupid*, just *misguided*). It's also **absolutely toxic** to a further understanding of what happened, and how to prevent it the next time it or something similar may happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "software update" spell solved it.  I had a number of updates come down last night and everything seems to work now.

Comment: You may accept your own answer if this solved your problem.